# How to make test case of if condition with operator && and || in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I am trying to write test case for this one and it is failing for npm test:

This is my function in ts file:

```
fromToHours(){
    let from = this.form.controls.workingHoursFrom.value;
    let to = this.form.controls.workingHoursTo.value;
    if((from == "" && to != "") || (from != "" && to == "")){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      return true;
    }
  }
```

This is my spec.ts file and this test case is failing for npm test:

```
it('should test fromToHours()', () => {
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(true);
    let from = "";
    let to = "";
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue(from);
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue(to);
    from = "17:00";
    to = null;
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(false);
    from = null;
    to = "17:00";
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(false);
  });
```

How to make this test case right?

Comment: Your assignments are have no effect as you are reasigning from/to variable and not whatever is set to te controls\

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside if that test case is valid or not, and if it makes any sense - you are assigning values to the controls the wrong way

```
//bad description of test, you are not testing if test is testing fromToHours method. Could be rather "returns true if no values are provided"

it('should test fromToHours()', () => {
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(true);
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue("17:00");
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue(null);
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(false);
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue(null);
    component.form.controls['workingHoursTo'].setValue("17:00");
    expect(component.fromToHours()).toEqual(false);
  });
```

You cannot reassign variable and expect that in every place that you have previously used that variable change will be in effect.

Comment: Think of upvoting and accepting answer if it was usefull @msm